# Inception v3, train test and validation splits in retrain.py

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have been using tensorflow's retrain.py script for the inception v3 model to build a multilabel classification model, I found some code in the script that I don't fully understand, I'm asking for help clarifying what it does:

```
 for file_name in file_list:
        base_name = os.path.basename(file_name)
        # We want to ignore anything after '_nohash_' in the file name when
        # deciding which set to put an image in, the data set creator has a way of
        # grouping photos that are close variations of each other. For example
        # this is used in the plant disease data set to group multiple pictures of
        # the same leaf.
        hash_name = re.sub(r'_nohash_.*$', '', file_name)
        # This looks a bit magical, but we need to decide whether this file should
        # go into the training, testing, or validation sets, and we want to keep
        # existing files in the same set even if more files are subsequently
        # added.
        # To do that, we need a stable way of deciding based on just the file name
        # itself, so we do a hash of that and then use that to generate a
        # probability value that we use to assign it.
        hash_name_hashed = hashlib.sha1(compat.as_bytes(hash_name)).hexdigest()
        percentage_hash = ((int(hash_name_hashed, 16) %
                            (MAX_NUM_IMAGES_PER_CLASS + 1)) *
                           (100.0 / MAX_NUM_IMAGES_PER_CLASS))
        if percentage_hash < validation_percentage:
            validation_images.append(base_name)
        elif percentage_hash < (testing_percentage + validation_percentage):
            testing_images.append(base_name)
        else:
            training_images.append(base_name)
```

Is there a way to name the images to decide which ones go to the train set, validation set or test set? If someone has a link for the plant disease dataset mentioned here that would also be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Link for a [plant disease dataset][1] on kaggle


  [1]: https://www.kaggle.com/c/plant-pathology-2020-fgvc7/data